# How to listen hookbin webhook in Python?

Tags: python, webhooks

hookbin Webhooks allows the user to specify the URL of an application that will receive data, in json format, when an event occurs. For example when an event is updated in hookbin. I want to create a python script that will receive this data and print it out. How is the best way to create this python script?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to **scrape** the hookbin website. I tried and so far it's a pain, definitely possible but you have to make requests exactly as though you were in a browser. If you need a webhook to listen to content being sent, I'd just use a discord webhook and have a bot read them in a private server.

Bot Script

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'Make your bot at https://discord.com/developers/applications'

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.author.bot:
        data = message.content
        await message.channel.send(f"Received {data}")
        print(data)
        # anything else you wanted to do with the data
        


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Webhook Script

```
import requests

hook = 'Your Discord Webhook'

data = {
  "content": "This is the data that gets printed to terminal through the bot"
}

r = requests.post(hook, json=data)
```

Only downside is you can't get very specific details, but if you need to get just the content it works fine. Making the Bot and webhook are real ez. Make the bot by going to the dev portal and invite it to a private server, then make the webhook by going under "Intergrations" in any text channel

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onhg6.png)

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZCh0.png)